# How to display image from url on rasberry pi connected to a monitor?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am using RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE on Raspberry Pie 3. I have connected it to a monitor and written a python code which subscribes to a `mqtt` Message. The functionality is, it receives message in form of string which is a url of the image. It is supposed to display image on the monitor. The python code is:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib
import io
import cv2
import numpy as np

URL= "http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"
stream = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
image = np.asarray(bytearray(stream),dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("Image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But the image is not displayed and I get warning message `gtk-warning ** cannot open display`.

Please let me know how it should work.

Comment: Does your Pi start a GUI? Or only a command line environment?

Comment: Its in the command line environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with

```
 import os
 os.system("sudo killall fbi")
 os.system("sudo fbi -T 1 image1.jpg")
```